# nativescript-ng2-magic looks for html in wrong path

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a problem with nativescript-ng2-magic. I have a web app, and now I am trying to build a mobile app by using nativescript-ng2-magic for sharing code.

In my starting component (app.component.*) (path: app/app/) I have included page-router-outlet to be redirected to the login page. For this, I have declared the path in app.routing.ts 
`{path: "", redirectTo: "/login"}`.

The files for the login page are under app/components/login. in login.routing I declared the path 
`{ path: "login", component: LoginComponent }`.  Then I am doing a  `RouterModule.forChild(loginRoutes);`

The login component (same path as the login.routing.ts) looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: "login",
  templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./login.common.css"],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
 ...
}
```

When I want to start the mobile app I got the error message:

Error: File /data/data/org.nativescript.nativescript/files/app/app/login.component.tns.html does not exist.

That's right. As I wrote above the file is under app/app/components/login. Why is nativscript-ng2-magic looking in the wrong path?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should set the full path to the `login.component.html`and `login.common.css`. For example

```
@Component({
  selector: "login",
  templateUrl: "components/loginlogin.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["components/loginlogin.common.css"],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
 ...
}
```

Comment: With @Component({ selector: "login", templateUrl: "./components/login/login.component.html", styleUrls: ["./components/login/login.common.css"], }) export class LoginComponent implements OnInit { ... } the mobile app works, but then the Web-App doesn't work because the files are not found

Comment: Leo try using module.id and relative paths example here https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/master/app/file-system/file-system-examples.component.ts#L13-L14

Comment: Could you please give an short example! I think I have misunderstood the relative path. Relative to which file?